# music21 getElementsByClass not showing any output for class stream.Voice

Tags: python, midi, music21

I am struggling to understand why the below code is throwing an error when it ran seamlessly about a year back. The code snippet is from a popular Coursera course. Does the Music21 package has some recent changes around `stream.Voice`?

```
data_fn = 'data/original_metheny.mid'
midi_data = converter.parse(data_fn)
melody_stream = midi_data[5] # For Metheny piece, Melody is Part #5.
melody1, melody2 = melody_stream.getElementsByClass(stream.Voice)
```

The error thrown is `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`, which means there is no output for `stream.Voice` class when previously there were outputs for the same data (midi file). `melody_stream.getElementsByClass('Measure')` does show outputs.

Can you guide how to debug this?

Comment: By the way, what is the Coursera course? This same code example was used in a question on the mailing list.

Comment: deeplearning.ai course on sequence modeling. Exercise example on Jazz improvisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one of the improvements in music21 v.7 is that files imported from MIDI now have a similar representation to files imported from MusicXML and other formats. Specifically, Parts now have Measures, which may or may not have Voices, rather than Parts directly containing Voices. Code should not depend on finding Voices directly contained in Parts, which is what this example was doing.

Instead, use this code to find all the measure-voices:

```
melody_stream.recurse().getElementsByClass(stream.Voice)
```

Or, equivalently, use the shortcut syntax in v.7:

```
melody_stream[stream.Voice]
```

Or, if you don't want the measures at all, call `flatten()` or `chordify()` depending on your use case.

Comment: I'm playing with the same example and made change as per your comment

---> 31 melody1, melody2 = melody_stream[stream.Voice];
     32 for j in melody2:
     33     melody1.insert(j.offset, j)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Line 29 in this file https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-deep-learning-specialization/blob/master/C5%20-%20Sequence%20Models/Week%201/Jazz%20improvisation%20with%20LSTM/preprocess.py

Comment: Ah, but you omitted the `.recurse()`. If you're not sure when to use `recurse()`, here's a mailing list post with a gentle introduction to nested streams and how to access them: https://groups.google.com/g/music21list/c/4zjsrZXkc2w/m/TjeTy1N1AQAJ

Comment: @AdityaMittal only linked the original, but meant that even with the recurse() the return will be empty, which I can confirm. The very same code does not return anything using "melody_stream.recurse().getElementsByClass(stream.Voice)" or the other method.

Comment: My guess is that the "melody_stream = midi_data[5]" before that simply doesn't return the same item as it used to, so there is no use applying the function.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was downgrading **music21** package to a version older than 7.x. So if you already have a newer version of **music21** package installed, remove it using `pip uninstall music21`, Then install the 6.7.0 version using `pip install music21==6.7.0`.