# music21 getElementsByClass

Tags: python, midi, music21

The code snippet is from a popular Coursera course

```
midi_data = converter.parse(data_fn)
# Get melody part, compress into single voice.
melody_stream = midi_data[5]     # For Metheny piece, Melody is Part #5.
melody1, melody2 = melody_stream.getElementsByClass(stream.Voice)
```

The error thrown is:-

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

and when using this:-

```
melody1, melody2 = melody_stream.recurse().getElementsByClass(stream.Voice)
```

the error thrown is:-

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can you guide how to debug this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [music21 getElementsByClass not showing any output for class stream.Voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040337/music21-getelementsbyclass-not-showing-any-output-for-class-stream-voice)

Answer (score 1):

the newest version of music21 (7.x) has some changes about the returns of

`melody_stream.getElementsByClass()`

if u don't wanna examine it, try the old version to avoid this problem like:

```
pip install music21==6.7.0
```